# angular6: I want my inherited component to have some propertys of the parent

Tags: angular, inheritance, components, angular6

I have a table where every table-cell is a different instance of a component. Depending on the data (date, text, links) I'm using different components.

As these components have a lot in common I introduced a TableCellMasterComponent which is extended by all other type of table-cells.

All my components have the same host property:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'td[app-text-col]',
  templateUrl: './text-col.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./text-col.component.css'],
  host: {
    "[hidden]": "col.deactivated"
  },
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class TextColComponent extends TableCellMasterComponent{
}
```

Is it possible to somehow move this to the TableCellMasterComponent?

Also I would love to give all of them a contextmenu. But as I see it, it isn't possible to add HTML in the Master. Is that true?

Can I move the changeDetection to the Master?

Comment: Check out this blog post about [Encapsulation](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/). Maybe you'll find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@Component` decorator metadata is not inherited so you cannot move some things to the base class. `@Input` and `@Output` properties get inherited.

There is a solution for the host property you can use a `@HostBinding` instead and this will get inherited. For example your binding you can do like this:

```
@HostBinding('hidden') get hidden(): boolean { return col.deactivated; }
```

Comment: I tried this, the problem with this is that the property col.deactivated changes over time and with the old solution the columns would react to it. With this solution they don't. Sadly I can't bind to [hidden]

Comment: Can you give more information about where the `col.deactivated` comes from? I have made a simple sample on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxdrzt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) and it works ok. I'm binding to a property of the same component.

Comment: Yeah but in your example it is only checked on startup. There is no change later. On my example the col-object is handed in as an @Input

Comment: It changes if you press the Toggle button. Then you can see live that it updates the binding and the content is hidden or shown.

Comment: you are totally right and it also works, must have been tired when I tested this, thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

I also created a [Stackblitz](https://angular-2czpy3.stackblitz.io) which solves them the only way I know how. Credit to AlesD for solving your first problem, all you needed to do to solve the issue is add `@Input()` onto visibility which you control in the parent element.

Your issue with a context menu is less straightforward. One option that I quickly tried to show in my stackblitz using [ngx-contextmenu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-contextmenu) is done using nested components. There's a nice tutorial [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2)

As you discovered, you have to choose between using extends, or using a nested component. In my example, I use both, but it may make the most sense to just use one or the other depending:

- If your context menus are different and redundancy is not that big an issue, use extends, and build the context menu manually on each component
- if the context menus are all going to be the same, I would drop the extends entirely and use a nested component. You can access the nested component using @ViewChild to gain access to the attributes you need.
- Using both (like in my example) was used mostly for demonstrating as I don't understand the whole context of your application, but if you could abstract your cells to use a common interface or class you can pass in to the contextMenu, limiting the number of inputs, it may make sense for you.

Comment: I would love to also award you a bounty, sadly I can only do that once, thanks so much for your help